# requirejs - i am not getting loaded and "require" function not called

Tags: requirejs

In my simple index file i added the "requirejs" - and calling the define function, but i am not getting any response:

Html :

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script data-main="js/main" src="js/lib/require.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js :

```
require.config({
    baseUrl : "js"
})

require(function () {
    alert("hi");
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution: and it describes as :

```
require(["helper/util"], function(util) {
    //This function is called when scripts/helper/util.js is loaded.
    //If util.js calls define(), then this function is not fired until
    //util's dependencies have loaded, and the util argument will hold
    //the module value for "helper/util".
});
```

at here : http://requirejs.org/docs/start.html

thanks for all.